# how to make a uninstall option in C# program?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

i want to make a uninstall option in my C# program?
can u help for this?
and provide some code also

Answer (score 0):

You can create an installation project which will automatically add support for uninstallation. Under `Other Project Types` you have `Setup and Deployment`. There is **InstallShield LE** and **Visual Studio Installer**. If you choose Setup Project under Visual Studio Installer project, you will have uninstall as part of the built project.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your application via a `Visual Studio Setup and Deployment Project`, an uninstaller will come standard with the installation.  It will be available in the Add/Remove Programs of the control panel.

Comment: but i want to provid this option in my program

Answer (score 0):

see this video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z-xFLltALg0

If you want the executable to remove itself. aka self-destruct. Check out this blog http://blog.pedroliska.com/2010/05/20/c-self-destruct-windows-app/

Comment: i want to make unintall option in my project only, if user click on uninstall then all program will uninstall........ plz help for this